# Meaning behind underscore character in regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

**Note:** My program works, I am just looking for an explanation as to why.

I have a java program that reads a file, counts the words in said file, and outputs the words and counts to another file. In the first part of my I use a regular expression to replace any character not a letter and replace it with an empty string.

```
freq.add(in.next().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", ""));
```

This however does not account for hyphenated words so I changed the regEx to:

```
freq.add(in.next().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z_-]", ""));
```

My question is, why does adding the underscore and hyphen work? What is the meaning behind the underscore character?

While I'm asking questions, are regex the same for all languages?

Also, if this is answered somewhere else I apologize, I did numerous searches with no luck.

Comment: The underscore is a literal underscore character, simply put.

Comment: @hwnd Do I even need it in my code then?

Comment: It isn't catching your hyphenated text because of `_-` but rather simply due to `-`. Try `[^A-Za-z-]` and see. Also, there are variants of regex, but mostly mutually intelligible. Check out [regex101](http://regex101.com/) for some nifty help and explanation. take your example there and explore.

Comment: Note: `-` in regular expression character classes *is* special. When it's not the final character in the class (initial might be legal too), it's the range character (that makes something like `a-z` mean all lowercase ASCII letters) unless escaped.

Comment: @Shawn Mehan It works both with and without the underscore.

Comment: @Moose: Until you have `_` in the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing special about an underscore in a regular expression, it's just a normal character like A. A hyphen at the end of a character class isn't special either, although it is when between two other characters, as you've used it to match all letters by saying A-Z for example.

Regular expressions are **similar** between most languages, but some of the more esoteric features can be different or missing from a language.

Comment: A clue please why this was voted down? Is it wrong? If so, I'd love a correction.

Comment: Your answer is not more substantial than the comments. If you're going to put in an answer, at least make it substantial. Perhaps you could reference the differences and flavors of regex. Perhaps you list the alternate forms of character classes and underscore and hyphen. Something that doesn't basically regurgitate the comments.

Comment: I was posting my answer as the comments were being posted (note they're within a minute or two of each other), when I started there weren't any comments. In the future I'll refresh after I've entered my answer and before posting it to check for this situation. Thanks.

Comment: @Shawn Mehan If a user answers a question with a comment, restating that information as an answer [is actively encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117268/351462) as long as credit is given. In this case blm's answer was written independently and it provides enough information to answer the question as-is.